# Is there any way to install Microsoft Visual Studio on a 4GB RAM PC without admin rights like a zip to extract and run?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I don't have admin rights so I want to install Visual Studio and the compiler to follow along The Cherno's tutorial on YouTube. Is there any alternative to the installer so that I don't need the admin rights ? Standalone zip/tarballs ?

Comment: In short: no. But you can install [mingw](https://superuser.com/questions/1425823/installing-mingw-w64-without-admin-rights) and VS Code without admin rights.

Comment: @rustyx does OpenGL work with MinGW ?